# Can I use nodeJS fs.readFile to read multiple zip files located in the same directory?

Tags: node.js, fs, zip, jszip

I have three different zip files located in a single directory called 'data.' Each zip has a similar structure if you unzip it: they all contain a single directory and within the directory are many different csv files.

I am currently trying to use readFile from the 'fs' module to read each zip file **individually** into memory as a node Buffer using the following function:

```
/**
 * Wraps readFile in a promise.
 * @param path The location of the file to read: absolute path.
 * @returns A buffer containing the contents of the file.
 */
public static readFileAsync(path: string): Promise<Buffer> {
    return new Promise<Buffer>((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(path, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }

            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

After retrieving the data, I then want to convert it to base64. After converting to base64, I use the JSZip library to parse the base64 into js objects.

All that appears to work fine until I examine the results of parsing the base64 strings: **All of the data in my individual zip files are merged together**. The csvs from the different zips are all being read as though they were coming from a single zip.

I have tried handing readFile both a relative and an absolute path to each individual zip file. This always results in all the zips being read as one.

Is it possible to use fs.readFile to read each zip individually into memory?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can use fs.readdir to read directory and loop over items to read the each file individually. You can prepare an array of promisified fs.readFile and then use Promise.all to get all outputs at the same time

Comment: Thank you for the input. I actually found that my issue was simply that I was using the same instance of JSZip to read the base64 data... so I was aggregating the results myself without realizing it... Thanks anyway for the help.

Comment: great ..you solved it yourself :)